# For $x \in \mathbb{R}$, if $x$ is irrational then $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is irrational.

Tags: proof-explanation

Getting caught up on this problem. what i got so far.

Contrapositive: For $x \in \mathbb{R}$, if $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is rational, then $x$ is rational.

If   $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is rational then there must exist an $a,b \in Z, b \neq 0$ such that

$$\sqrt[3]{x}=\frac{a}{b}$$
$$x=\frac{a^3}{b^3}$$
$$b^3\cdot x=a^3$$

As $b^3$ is a multiple of $a^3$, $x$ by defintion can not be rational as they share a common factor.

I think im taking the wrong approach to this problem and should try maybe going by contradiction? or both. Or is the original statement false?

Answer (score 5):

you were already finished at $x=\frac{a^3}{b^3}$, any number of this form is immediately rational.

Comment: is this all i need to finish the problem or do i need to say more about x.......As \( a,b \in \Z \), the cubed root of \(x\) must be rational as by definition of a rational number and it follows that if the cubed root of \(x\) is rational then \(x\) must be rational.

Comment: well, you wanted to prove that if $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is rational then so is $x$, and that is exactly what you did.

Comment: If $a$ is an integer then $a^3$ certainly is... .likewise with $b$ and $b^3$.